# How do you change just one fill in the appearance of many objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, texture, fill, appearance

TLDR; I can't seem to drag a fill from the swatches to replace one of two fills defined in an appearance.  How do you do this?

When I update an appearance with multiple fills, it updates both fills even if nothing has changed on the other, (like dragging an updated appearance over an object that has an older version like the appearance).

This is problematic because I have one fill with a Texture and another fill with a Gradient.   I don't want the gradients to have to change, (and therefore have to update all of the objects whose gradients reset).

***Is there a good way to manage separating textures and gradients***, maybe with the appearance feature, in a way that let's me update / change them separately?

Comment: There's no need to ever *drag* a swatch anywhere. Select an objet, or appearance attribute, and merely *click* the swatch.

Answer (score 1):

With the object Selected on the Artboard- Go to the Appearance Panel (Window> Appearance) simply click on one of the Fills to select *only it*. It will show with a blue highlight. Then you can click on a new Fill color to assign that color to only that Fill.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do this with Graphic Styles, or do you have to use Swatches?   But most importantly, I am trying to update many objects at the same time with the new fill.  (The Gradient is on the top of the appearance panel, the texture is below it.)